# 2 ref cursors for the same data set

Tags: plsql

Can you explain me how to create 2 cursors for the same result set?
I have 
something like the following:

```
declare
   emp_id_c1 number;
   emp_id_c2 number;
   c1 sys_refcursor;
   c2 sys_refcursor;
begin
  open c1 for with x as select emp_id from emp;
  c2 := c1;      
  loop
   fetch c1 into emp_id_c1;
   dbms_output.put_line('some');
   loop
     fetch c2 into emp_id_c2;
       dbms_output();
    exit when c2%notfound;
   end loop;
   exit when c1%notfound;
  end loop;
end;
```

Thank you

Comment: Ref cursors are by definition “by reference” so c1 and c2 are the same thing. Also a cursor is the specification for a result set, so I’m not sure what you mean by two cursors for one result set.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Could you explain it, based on Scott's sample schema (EMP and DEPT tables)?

Comment: Hi, I want to iterate 2 times on the same data set, and playing with refcursor, If c1 and c2 are the same thing how can I have these 2 as separate objects c1 and c2 with the same set of data? Is it any way to pass the value from c1 into c2? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your goal, but I know that when you want to make a nested loop with two cursors you are making a mistake with 99% probability. If you need to compare data in two cursors, combine them into one SQL query and process it. The main reason is performance. A nested loop can decrease the performance 100 times compared with the pure SQL. For example, for cursors based on the query

```
select column1 from table1 where <condition1>
```

and

```
select column2 from table2 where <condition2>
```

If you need to do something with rows having the same data, do the following:

```
declare
  val1 number;
  val2 number;
  cursor c1 is
    select column1, column2
      from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column2
     where <condition1> and <condition2>;
begin
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 into val1, val2;
    exit when c1%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('some text to output');
  end loop;
end;
```

**UPD**
If you *really* need the 2 nested loops over the same data, you can open the second cursor independently. In your code, instead of

```
c2 := c1;
```

write

```
open c2 for ...
```

*inside* the first loop:

```
open c1 for ...
loop
   fetch c1 into emp_id_c1;
   ...
   open c2 for ...
   loop
     ...
   end loop; -- inner loop
end loop; -- outer loop
```

Comment: This is 1 iteration, I need 2 iterations over the same set of data. I can achieve this with by declaring a type of records. I was wondering how do I declare another cursor c2 as a separate object from c1

Comment: 2 iterations over the same set of data? I don't see any practical sense in this unless it is homework. But I will add what you want to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per you Question same data set, to fill two different cursor and then fill the cursor , then you are following the correct approach:

```
  declare
   emp_id_c1 number;
   emp_id_c2 number;
   c1 sys_refcursor;
   c2 sys_refcursor;
begin    
  open c1 for 
  select EmpID from Table1;
   c2 := c1;      
  loop
   fetch c1 into emp_id_c1;
   dbms_output.put_line('Cusrsor 1 data');
   loop
     fetch c2 into emp_id_c2;
        dbms_output.put_line('Cusrsor 2 data');
       dbms_output.put_line(emp_id_c2);
    exit when c2%notfound;
   end loop;
   exit when c1%notfound;
  end loop;
end;
```